# Can`t query using 'where' between two tables in one DB?

Tags: android, android-room

Today one problem came to me when I was learning Room in Android.

Everything is ok but I just can`t query with where between two tables.

Here are my codes:

......................................................................................................................................................

this code works well

```
@Query("select users.id,users.name from users where score > :score and assist > :assist")

List<UserSimple> getUserWithLimits(int score,int assist);
```

but the follow one can`t get anything:

```
@Query("select users.id,users.name from users,performs where users.id = performs.id and performs.score > :score and performs.assist > :assist")

List<UserSimple> getUserWithLimits(int score,int assist);
```

and here are my tables created using Room:
........................................................................................................................................................
     user table:

```
 @Entity(tableName = "users", 
        primaryKeys = {"id", "name"},
        indices = {
                @Index(value = "id", unique = true)
        })
public class User {
    @android.support.annotation.NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @android.support.annotation.NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "position")
    private String position;

    @Embedded
    private UserPerforms performs;

    @Ignore
    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String name, String position, UserPerforms performs) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.performs = performs;
    }

    getters/setters/toString()...
}
```

........................................................................................................................................................
   performs table:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "performs",
        primaryKeys = "p_id",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = User.class
                , parentColumns = "id"
                , childColumns = "p_id")) //定义主键
public class UserPerforms {
    @android.support.annotation.NonNull //
    @ColumnInfo(name = "p_id")
    private String p_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "score")
    private int score;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "assist")
    private int assist;

    @Ignore
    public UserPerforms() {
    }

    public UserPerforms(String p_id, int score, int assist) {
        this.p_id = p_id;
        this.score = score;
        this.assist = assist;
    }

    ...getters/setters/toString()..

}
```

........................................................................................................................................................
userSimple class:

```
public class UserSimple {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;

    ...getters/setters/toString()

    public UserSimple(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but the follow one can't get anything" -- try an explicit `JOIN`: `SELECT users.id,users.name FROM users JOIN performs ON users.id = performs.id WHERE performs.score > :score AND performs.assist > :assist`

Comment: where users.id = performs.id  <-- are you sure this is the correct column to join on?

Answer (score 0):

You are joining wrong columns. Your id column in the performs table is p_id, not id. Try this:

```
@Query("select users.id,users.name from users,performs where users.id = performs.p_id and performs.score > :score and performs.assist > :assist")
```